# React-navigation 'Home' should declare a screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to get a handle on react-navigation by making a dead simple app; I just want two screens with buttons you can click on to go between them.  Here's my code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Button
} from 'react-native';

import {
    StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

import OtherPage from './OtherPage';

const Home = ({navigation}) => (
    <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Welcome</Text>
        <Button title="Other Page" onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('OtherPage')
        }}></Button>
    </View>
);

const Nav = StackNavigator(
    {
        OtherPage: { screen: OtherPage},
        Index: {
            screen: Home
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Index',
    }
);

export default () => <Nav />;
```

OtherPage.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    View,
    Button
} from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const OtherPage = ({navigation}) => (
    <View>
        <Text>Other Page</Text>
        <Button title="Go Home" onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        }}></Button>
    </View>
);

import Home from './App';
const Nav = StackNavigator(
    {
        OtherPage: { screen: OtherPage},
        Home: { screen: Home }, // THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
    },
);

export default () => <Nav />;
```

For some reason what I get back from `import Home from './App';` isn't a `screen` and so I get the error `Route 'Home' should declare a screen`.  It's definitely that line that's causing the problem, if I comment it out then the app loads and I can click the button on the home screen to go to the other page, but then of course I'm stuck there and can't go back.

What's confusing me is that these files are essentially identical in how everything's declared, and for some reason `import OtherPage from './OtherPage';` is a valid `screen` but `import Home from './App';` isn't.

Can anyone help me out?  What am I doing wrong?